# Two side by side divs that will go to single column in mobile view x2

Tags: css

I have a page where I want to display four 5-item ordered lists. I want to display this in sort of a 2x2 table fashion, but have all 4 of these lists go to a single column in mobile view.

I am currently using float:left to display this and then using float:none in my mobile.css to get the single column display I desire.

Here is the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ygnh05ro/).

This look OK?

(Here is HTML. Please see JSFiddle above.)

```
<div style="width=100%;overflow:hidden;">

<div class="foodlist" style="float:left;min-width:250px;padding:10px 0 10px;">
<strong>Fruit</strong> 
<ol>
<li>Apples </li>
<li>Oranges </li> 
<li>Pears </li> 
<li>Lemons </li>
<li>Limes </li>
</ol>
</div>

<div class="foodlist" style="float:left;min-width:250px;padding:10px 0 10px;">
<strong>Veggies</strong>
<ol>
<li>Carrots </li>
<li>Peas </li>
<li>Corn </li> 
<li>Peppers </li> 
<li>Cucumber </li> 
</ol>
</div>

</div>

<div style="width=100%;overflow:hidden;">

<div class="foodlist" style="float:left;min-width:250px;padding:10px 0 10px;">
<strong>Meats</strong> 
<ol>
<li>Bacon </li>
<li>Chicken </li>
<li>Pork </li> 
<li>Beef </li> 
<li>Turkey </li> 
</ol>
</div>

<div class="foodlist" style="float:left;min-width:250px;padding:10px 0 10px;">
<strong>Desserts</strong>
<ol>
<li>Apple Pie </li>
<li>Chocolate Cake </li>
<li>Brownies </li> 
<li>Ice Cream </li> 
<li>Pastries </li> 
</ol>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to use `float: none;`. Since the divs are floated they will stack if there is not enough horizontal space hold it. Also, please avoid using `important`. Only use it in extreme instances.

Comment: you can also use display:inline-block instead of float:left and remove the @media part of css.

Answer (score 0):

Or U can make width of blocks =100% after @media.